# Python Environment Migration (without Docker) from one Windows Machine to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, python-venv

I've been struggling with Python environment capture for a long time and I would like to ask: what do members of the Python community do to solve this problem?

As an example, on my team we have multiple Windows machines running Windows 10 and would like to be able to quickly change from one python environment for troubleshooting, to make use of functionality only present with one environment, or to regress to a working environment.

Note: My company does not want to purchase licenses for Docker or Anaconda.

Thanks!

Process:

1. Install Python3X on Windows machine in directory "ProgramFiles/Python3X"
2. Make sure Python3X and Python3X/Scripts are in windows path by editing Windows Environment Variables
3. Navigate to ProgramFiles/PythonVenv/Python3X and run the command

```
python3X -v venv <venv_name>
```

4.Then navigate to ProgramFiles/PythonVenv/Python3X/<venv_name>/Scripts and make sure you can activate by running command

```
activate.bat
```

5. Zip up ProgramFiles/PythonVenv/Python3X/<venv_name>
6. Perform steps 1-3 on the target machine and copy the zipped python venv into ProgramFiles/PythonVenv/Python3X
7. Make sure you can activate the venv and perform step 4 on the target machine

Initially this seems to work, and when I activate the transplanted venv and run

```
pip3.X list
```

I see all the packages I installed on the original machine.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I prefer using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/). It is much more convenient rather than using only venv. Check [Managing environments](https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/) guide, maybe this is what you are looking for.

Re-creating the environment on another machine can be done by using the same poetry.lock file.